# How to get previous page url while navigating to new page in angular 4

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router, angular4-router

I tried given below code. But previous url can't get in service pages

```
previousUrl: string;
constructor(router: Router) {
  router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe(e => {
    console.log('prev:', this.previousUrl);
    this.previousUrl = e.url;
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get in services pages"?

Comment: I want to send the previous url to back end while performing a function in current page

Comment: You could use document.referrer : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp